# How to display error label in Cupertino TextField

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display an error text below a Cupertino TextField if the field is empty after a user pushes my login button. There seems to be no clear cut way to display an error label below the textfield like on android in any of the CupertinoTextfield parameters.

How do I achieve this?

Here is my code

```
CupertinoTextField(
        key: widget.key,
        keyboardType: widget.textInputType,
        placeholder: widget.errorText ?? widget.hint,
        style: widget.style,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        enabled: widget.enabled,
        controller: widget.textEditingController,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        obscureText: widget.obscureText,
        enableSuggestions: widget.enableSuggestions,
        autocorrect: widget.autocorrect,
        clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
        padding: widget.iosPaddings != null
            ? widget.iosPaddings!
            : const EdgeInsets.all(4),
      );
```

Comment: Would that error be a typical part of the iOS UI and Design System? I am not familiar with forms on iOS apps, but there's a chance it's not there because the Design System on iOS expects errors to be shown in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try `CupertinoTextFormFieldRow`:

```dart
CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
    prefix: Text('Email'),
    placeholder: 'mail@example.com',
    validator: (value) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please, enter your email';
      }

      return null;
    },
);
```

Have a look at the example with full form: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextFormFieldRow-class.html